# ADF: find pipelines by sink resource

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there an option to filter/find Azure DataFactory pipelines by "sink" resource they are using ?

For example I have a datasent linked as a SQL table "ddd.TABLE" and I want to find all pipelines that have something to do with it. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may not be exactly what you are looking for, but most assets have a "Related" feature that will show you where they are used. For example: go to the "Manage" tab and select "Linked Services". The "Related" column will show you how many references are in the system to that Linked Service:

[image]

Clicking on the number will open a flyout on the right side showing you which assets reference the service:

[image]

The list items are clickable and will open that asset. In this example the items are all Datasets. In the Dataset, under "Properties", you will find another "Related" tab that lists all the assets that reference the Dataset:

[image]

As before, the items in the list are clickable and will open the asset.

Comment: Oh, this is exactly what I was looking for! My properties tab in the dataset view was wrapped by default so I did not noticed. Thanks for showing it ! (I can filter pipelines from there much easier)